# Task.StartNew beginner issue

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((param,param2) => { Console.WriteLine("Test"); },
                                        TaskCreationOptions.None);
```

Error   1   Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 2 arguments

I am getting the above error. Couldn't understand what's going wrong.

Edited: Why it is accepting single parameters then

```
  Task.Factory.StartNew((param1) =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Task : {0}, outputing {1}- {2}",
                       param1, j.ToString(), param1));
                }
            }, string.Format("Tast Count " + ic++.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [several overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321421.aspx) to the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method.  The two you've mentioned in your question are:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Action, TaskCreationOptions)
Task.Factory.StartNew(Action<Object>, Object)
```

The methods do considerably different things.  The item of note, though, is the difference between `Action` and `Action<object>`.  Lambdas are essentially anonymous methods, so to get a visual of what these are, let's convert them to method signatures.

```
Action                 -> void AnonymousMethod()
Action<object>         -> void AnonymousMethod(object f)
Action<object, object> -> void AnonymousMethod(object f, object s)
```

In your first example, which doesn't compile, it is equivalent to the last one.  There is no overload for `Task.Factory.StartNew` that takes multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`StartNew` takes an `Action` delegate, which is defined as:

```
public delegate void Action()
```

That is, a method with no return value, and no parameters. You're attempting to pass two parameters into an action: `param` and `param2`.

Your code should look like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Test"); });
                    // ^^ Note: no "param" or "param2".
```

Also, `TaskCreationOptions` are attached to a custom task factory, not to the default one.

Comment: I don't think the TaskCreationOptions are passed to StartNew() either.

Comment: @Sepster Indeed - they are for a custom TaskFactory. I have edited my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: But that does not explain why it works with a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` takes 1 parameter, a `System.Action`.

And a `System.Action` according to [MSDN Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a
>   value.

You're trying to pass two parameters, by the looks?  You don't pass TaskCreationOptions.None to StartNew().  If you do want to pass options (which you don't, as you're using 'none') you'd make a custom task factory (passing the options to its constructor).